Apocalyptic cultivator manga—dimension-hopping regressor battles ghouls and evil sects alongside a shadow-portaling assassin and a goose-clone
I'm looking for a manga I read ages ago. I've been searching for ages. I can remember lots of the details; I just hope I'm not mixing multiple mangas together. Here are the details I remember:
It's a regressor murim/cultivator type, set in modern—post-modern, actually. He regresses, and soon the world is going to face an apocalypse. There are ghouls at first, I'm pretty sure, and over time they mutate. Humans can be turned into the mutated ones. I think he fights a mutated human for a lot of the first arc and ends up making it join his party to help fight other ghouls and the bad guys.
There's also a guy in an assassin organization. He can portal-go through shadow doors or something; I don't quite remember. There's a girl he likes. Her grandfather is one of the top ten powerhouses of the world. The top ten powerhouses are a big part of the first part of the manga.
Anyway, it turns out it's an evil sect or god that hops from worlds or dimensions, destroying them for power or something. He ends up going up multiple dimensions in the series. I don't remember much about the second dimension, but in the third dimension, he joins a sect or a clan that has a female sect leader who makes a clone of herself as a goose who talks and acts like a top disciple of the clan/sect.
There are also other major sects/clans, most notably that I remember is a sword sect and a monk one. There are also big powerhouses that stand equal to his female master. These masters are like gods.
Something else that happens: the sects get together for a joint competition or something, and a big part of it is the spirit beasts turn on their masters. But the MC clued in early, and he and the sect leaders set up a trap. The spirit beasts turning on the sects was a plan devised by an evil sect, most notably an evil master from another dimension more powerful than the leaders.
Another iconic thing I remember: there's a really powerful man chained to a big column who talks to him when he cultivates or tries breaking through to the next level and helps him break through.
I think the monk in the big 3 on the third dimension dies preventing the evil guy from getting into their dimension.
Oh yeah, I remember the MC got sucked into the portal to the evil guy's dimension. I believe that's where it was up to when I read it.

I edited the post's title to be more descriptive. If there's something incorrect, please [edit] it.

How long ago is "ages ago"? i.e. can you give us a year (or range of years) when you read this?

No clue to be honest it feels like 2 years ago ish but I can’t be sure

I believe I’ve finally found the manhwa I have been looking for it’s called: WORLD’S APOCALYPSE ONLINE
I’m sure I got lots of the details wrong I’ll give it a read and see how far off my description was.
